# Is it possible to construct two subsequences of a sequence X with specific properties such that the two subsequence sums are the same?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, set-partition

I have been thinking about a certain variant of a problem from an Olympiad:

A sequence $X =a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\;$consists of positive integers, where $a_i \le i$ for $1 \le i \le n$, and $n \ge 2$. The sum of the elements in $X$ is even. Prove that one can split $X$ into two subsequences such that the sum of the elements in each subsequence is the same.

My first step was to try to construct a subsequence and bound the sum of the elements, but I have not found I have made any progress after this step. I have also thought of trying to apply the Pigeonhole Principle, but I am not quite sure how to approach this problem with it.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Which Olympiad is it from? There may already be a published solution for it.

Comment: @Zane Morgan: Do you mean a sequence, rather than a set?

Comment: @quasi I think if one interprets X as a sequence, it also works.

Comment: @Zane Morgan: If $X$ is a set, then the constraints force $a_i=i$, for all $i$.

Comment: @coffeemath I thought of this problem after looking at a loosely related Olympiad problem, so I do not have access to an official solution.

Comment: Do you know that it is possible to splt $X$ as requested?

Comment: @ Fabio Somenzi Yes it is always possible to split X. Another way to think about the problem may be to show one can always make ± a1 ± a2 ± · · · ± an equal 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say that a sequence $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ has *property (*)* if $n \geq 2$ and each $a_i$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $i$.  We will call a sequence $\mathbf{a}$ *permissible* if it has property (*) and $\sum_i a_i$ is even.  We want to show that

> **Claim 1**
>   Every permissible sequence $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ can be split into two subsequences $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ such that $\sum_i b_i = \sum_i c_i$.

Now, consider the the following claim about sequences with property (*).

> **Claim 2**
>   For every integer $m$ such that $0 \leq m \leq n + 1$, every sequence $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ with property (*) can be split into two subsequences $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ such that $\left|\sum_i b_i - \sum_i c_i - m\right| \leq 1$.

We argue that Claim 2 implies Claim 1.  Suppose that Claim 2 holds and consider a permissible sequence $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$.  By Claim 2 with $m = 0$, $\mathbf{a}$ can be split into two subsequences $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ such that $\left|\sum_i b_i - \sum_i c_i\right| \leq 1$.  Since $\sum_i a_i$ is even, $\sum_i b_i - \sum_i c_i$ is also even so $\sum_i b_i = \sum_i c_i$.

Thus, it suffices to prove Claim 2.  We do this by induction as follows.

The base case is $n = 2$.  There are exactly two sequences with property (*) for $n = 2$: $(1, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$.

Suppose $\mathbf{a} = (1, 1)$.  We know that $0 \leq m \leq 3$.  If $0 \leq m \leq 1$, then by choosing $\mathbf{b} = (1)$ and $\mathbf{c} = (1)$, we see that $$\left|\sum_i b_i - \sum_i c_i - m\right| = |m| \leq 1$$  If $2 \leq m \leq 3$, then after choosing $\mathbf{b} = (1, 1)$ and $\mathbf{c} = ()$ we find that $$\left|\sum_i b_i - \sum_i c_i - m\right| = |2 - m| \leq 1$$  Thus, the basis case holds for $\mathbf{a} = (1, 1)$.

Now assume that $\mathbf{a} = (1, 2)$.  If $0 \leq m \leq 2$ then let $\mathbf{b} = (2)$ and $\mathbf{c} = (1)$.  We have $$\left|\sum_i b_i - \sum_i c_i - m\right| = |1 - m| \leq 1$$  Finally, if $m = 3$, then we choose $\mathbf{b} = (1, 2)$ and $\mathbf{c} = ()$ and observe that $$\left|\sum_i b_i - \sum_i c_i - m\right| = |3 - m| = 0 \leq 1$$  Hence, the basis case holds for both $\mathbf{a} = (1, 1)$ and $\mathbf{a} = (1, 2)$.

Now, let us assume that Claim 2 holds for $n$.  We need to show that it holds for $n + 1$.  Consider an integer $m$ such that $0 \leq m \leq n + 2$ and a sequence $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_{n + 1})$ of length $n + 1$ with property (*).  Then $$m' = \left|m - a_{n + 1}\right| \leq n + 1$$ since $1 \leq a_{n + 1} \leq n + 1$.  By the inductive hypothesis, the sequence $\mathbf{a'} = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ can be split into subsequences $\mathbf{b'}$ and $\mathbf{c'}$ such that $$\left|\sum_i b_i' - \sum_i c_i' - m'\right| \leq 1$$

Now, either $m' = m - a_{n + 1}$ or $m' = a_{n + 1} - m$.  If $m' = m - a_{n + 1}$, then we have
\begin{align}
\left|\left(\sum_i b_i' + a_{n + 1}\right) - \sum_i c_i' - m\right| &= \left|\sum_i b_i' - \sum_i c_i' - m'\right| \leq 1
\end{align}
and the inductive case holds by letting $\mathbf{b} = (\mathbf{b'}, a_{n + 1})$ and $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{c'}$.

On the other hand, if $m' = a_{n + 1} - m$ then we see that
\begin{align}
\left|\left(\sum_i c_i' + a_{n + 1}\right) - \sum_i b_i' - m\right| &= \left|\sum_i c_i' - \sum_i b_i' + a_{n + 1} - m\right| \\
                                                                 {} &=
\left|\sum_i b_i' - \sum_i c_i' - a_{n + 1} + m\right| \\
                                                                 {} &= \left|\sum_i b_i' - \sum_i c_i' - m'\right| \\
                                                                 {} &\leq 1
\end{align}
so the inductive case holds by letting $\mathbf{b} = (\mathbf{c'}, a_{n + 1})$ and $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{b'}$.